# Parsing nested Values of AC list of Associative Arrays PHP

Tags: php, loops, indexing, foreach, associative-array

## Issue

New to PHP, trying to parse the values of an associative array that is in a list in PHP.

I come from a Pythonic background and am faced with refactoring a code I wrote in Python to a PHP CLI Script.
Working Pythonic Script - https://replit.com/@Terry-BrooksJr/AccesingDataAPI?v=1 (Note: To see Output CSV must edit in workspace)

### Sample Payload

https://pastebin.com/XF9vHeW2

Having Trouble with Accessing the Nested Values in an Assoc. Array.  - Seeing Note 4. IN PHP attempt

Here is the Function in Question:
Python

```py
def processSessions():
... Stuff to Open CVS File Pointer/Context Manager ... 
        for session in sessions['data']:
            for scoring in session['responses']:
                row_data = session['session_id'],scoring['question_reference'],scoring['question_type'],scoring['score'],scoring['max_score']
                csv_writer.writerow(row_data)
```

PHP Attempt

```php
function processSessions()
{

    $sessionDataCSV = 'SessionData'. date("Y-m-d") .'.csv';
    $sessions = downloadSessions();
    //NOTE - 1. Marshal/Serializes JSON Session Data to PHP Data Structure (associative array) Using json_decode() method
    $associoatedSessionDataArray = $sessions;

    //NOTE - 2. Opens File pointer to CSV Output
    $csv_output_file_pointer = fopen($sessionDataCSV, 'w');

    //NOTE - 3. Writes field names
    $fieldNames = array(
                        "ID",
                        "Reference",
                        "Type",
                        "Score",
                        "MaxScore"
                        );
    echo($associoatedSessionDataArray['data']);
    fputcsv($csv_output_file_pointer, $fieldNames);
    if (is_array($associoatedSessionDataArray) || is_object($associoatedSessionDataArray))
    {
     // NOTE - 4. Loop to Write Records
        foreach ($associoatedSessionDataArray as $session) {
            foreach ($associoatedSessionDataArray as $scoring) 
            fputcsv($csv_output_file_pointer, [$session['session_id'],$scoring['question_reference'],$session['question_type'],$session['score'],$session['max_score']]);

        }
    }
    // }
    else // If $myList was not an array, then this block is executed. 
    {
  echo "Unfortunately, an error occured.";
    }

    //NOTE - 5. Closes File pointer to CSV Output
    fclose($csv_output_file_pointer);
}
```

## Unexpected Output

```
ID,Reference,Type,Score,MaxScore
a9c92dc1-725c-456a-acc9-cdd32fd9f81b,,,6,8
ecc0bdb2-2fc9-4489-b2d6-b818a8b0ebc0,,,16,19
ee5ed0c3-f590-40d0-8480-8037914738ba,,,1,2
```

## My Ask

- Explain Why the Script is NOT iterating thru the entire list of responses `data['data']['responses']` (See Paste Bin link in #Sample Payload
- Why the output csv is `NULL` for the `Reference`,`Type` fields but parses and extracts the `score` and `max_score` when they are on the same level in terms of nesting.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. A PHP associative array is analogous to a Python dictionary. The nested loops should be similar.

Comment: What do you get in your CSV file?

Comment: But your PHP code seems to be processing ordinary lists, not dictionaries. How are you getting associative arrays instead of indexed arrays in PHP?

Comment: Maybe if you showed us an example of the data in `$sessions` and then an example of the output you want, the middle bit (FLOC) would be easier for us to help you with

Comment: Can you share a `var_dump($associatedSessionDataArray);` please (or just a sample if it's very big)?

Comment: Please remember, we have NO IDEA what your array looks like, if you cannot do more to help us understand your specific situation, we cannot help

Comment: `foreach ($associoatedSessionDataArray['data'] as $session) { foreach ($session['responses'] as $scoring) { ... } }`

Comment: @RobEyre - Updated the Question with a PasteBin of the JSON Payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you replace this part:

```
foreach ($associoatedSessionDataArray as $session) {
    foreach ($associoatedSessionDataArray as $scoring) 
    fputcsv($csv_output_file_pointer, [$session['session_id'],$scoring['question_reference'],$session['question_type'],$session['score'],$session['max_score']]);
}
```

with:

```
foreach ($associoatedSessionDataArray as $session) {
    foreach ($session['responses'] as $scoring) {
        fputcsv($csv_output_file_pointer, [
           $session['session_id'],
           $scoring['question_reference'],
           $scoring['question_type'],
           $scoring['score'],
           $scoring['max_score'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, just seen your question has been updated.  I think you're missing some data because you're using `$session` where you should have `$scoring` in some of the CSV output values.  You also have an error in the definitions of what you are looping over - see my answer